# Statistics of all/many tables in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

I'm writing a kind of summary page for my FileMaker solution.

For this, I have define a "statistics" table, which uses formula fields with ExecuteSQL to gather info from most tables, such as number of records, recently changed records, etc.

This strangely takes a long time - around 10 seconds when I have a total of about 20k records in about 10 tables. The same SQL on any database system shouldn't take more than some fractions of a second.

What could the reason be, what can I do about it and where can I start debugging to figure out what's causing all this time?

---

The actual code is, like this:

```
SQLAusführen ( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & _Stats::Table ; "" ; "" )
SQLAusführen ( "SELECT SUM(\"some_field_name\") FROM " & _Stats::Table ; "" ; "" )
```

Where "_Stats" is my statistics table, and it has a string field "Table" where I store the name of the other tables.

So each row in this _Stats table should have the stats for the table named in the "Table" field.

---

Update: I'm not using FileMaker server, this is a standalone client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can definitely talk about why it may be slow. Usually this has mostly to do with the size and complexity of your schema. That is "usually", as you have found.

Can you instead use the DDR ( database design report ) instead? Much will depend on what you are actually doing with this data. Tools like FMPerception also will give you many of the stats you are looking for. Again, depends on what you are doing with it.

Also, can you post your actual calculation? Is the statistic table using unstored calculations? Is the statistics table related to any of the other tables? These are a couple things that will affect how ExecuteSQL performs.

---

One thing to keep in mind, whether ExecuteSQL, a Perform Find, or relationship, it's all the same basic query under-the-hood. So if it would be slow doing it one way, it's going to likely be slow with any other directly related approach.

Taking these one at a time:

1. All records count.

   - Placing an unstored calc in the target table allows you to get the count of the records through the relationship, without triggering a transfer of all records to the client. You can get the value from the first record in the relationship. Super light way to get that info vs using Count which requires FileMaker to touch every record on the other side.
2. Sum of Records Matching a Value.

   - using a field on the _Stats table with a relationship to the target table will reduce how much work FileMaker has to do to give you an answer.
   - Then having a Summary field in the target table so sum the records may prove to be more efficient than using an aggregate function. The summary field will also only sum the records that match the relationship. ( just don't show that field on any of your layouts if you don't need it )

ExecuteSQL is fastest when it can just rely on a simple index lookup. Once you get outside of that, it's primarily about testing to find the sweet-spot. Typically, I will use ExecuteSQL for retrieving either a JSON object from a user table, or verifying a single field value. Once you get into sorting and aggregate functions, you step outside of the optimizations of the function.

Also note, if you have an open record ( that means you as the current user ), FileMaker Server doesn't know what data you have on the client side, and so it sends ALL of the records. That's why I asked if you were using unstored calcs with ExecuteSQL. It can seem slow when you can't control when the calculations fire. Often I will put the updating of that data into a scheduled script.

Comment: I only need a few simple counters, 3 or so per table. One is simply all records, the others are sum of records where some value is set or higher than X.

In SQL, it's just "SELECT SUM(value) FROM table".

See update to question for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I updated my answer to address specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a few pointers to start investigating. Also info: I'm not using FileMaker server, so transfer of data from server to client isn't my concern.

Comment: You can see similar behavior with that open record even on a local client, I believe. It's been a long time since I tested that one specifically. So I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: It does make a world of difference to approach it differently. For some reason, ExecuteSQL was really slow, but when I use FM scripting (freeze window, go through the layouts, make a search, store the results) it is blazing fast. Something is going on behind the scenes with ExecuteSQL but I have no time to debug it.

Comment: My guess is that ExecuteSQL is just touching something that isn't necessary for your use case. Finds, Relationships, and ExecuteSQL all use the same queries to get data from the records. ExecuteSQL has an additional layer, and without context may require a few extra steps. The `Sum` function is likely the source of the performance hit. If you remove that and just return the list of data, it may be faster.  You could then substitute the `¶` for a `+` and then evaluate if the list is small enough. That might be faster.

Comment: My suspicion is that the ExecuteSQL doesn't use the index, but a FM search does.

Comment: It will use the index when it can. But there are other decisions being made also. It's been talked about in some of the under-the-hood sessions at DevCon/Engage. One change, would be using a single field in `Count` function instead of `*`. Mostly, if it works, is fast... I'll use ExecuteSQL. If it's not, I just use another method.